# Show both sides of a relationship manyTomany Spring

Tags: java, spring, many-to-many

I have two entities (characters and movies) related many to many and I need that when one is consulted, for example characters, the related movies are displayed and vice versa. The problem is that I get serialization error if I use FetchType.EAGER or FetchType.LAZY. How could I achieve it?

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "_characters")
public class Characters {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "characters_movie",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "characters_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movies_id", insertable = false, updatable = false))
    private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "_movies")
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "movies")
    private Set<Characters> characters = new HashSet<>();
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
```

The solutions that I tried and did not work for you

@JsonManagedReference (shows only one side of the relationship)
@JsonIdentityInfo (shows, for example, a character's related movies but then shows the characters related to that movie and so on)
@Transactional (no function)

Comment: Please post your exception logs in details